# How to parse json response as Array

Tags: android, json

I am creating a an android app which show details of every members stored in the database.I receive details of members as json. This is my php code to send data from server to my app

```
<?php/*UserCake Version: 2.0.2 http://usercake.com */

require_once("models/config.php");
// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
$memberDetails = fetchAllMembers();
foreach($memberDetails as $ind=> $member){
$response["error"] = FALSE;
$response["id"] = $member["id"];
$response["member"]["name"] = $member["name"];
$response["member"]["profession"] = $member["profession"];
$response["member"]["brief_description"] = $member["brief_description"];
$response["member"]["description"] = $member["description"];

$response["member"]["filename"] = $member["filename"];

echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

This is my code to get that json

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            //hideDialog();

            try {
                //JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);


            //  Log.d(TAG, "JSON Array: " + jarray.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON Object: " + jObj.toString());

            //  boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (jObj!=null) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("id");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("member");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String profession = user.getString("profession");
                    String brief_description = user.getString("brief_description");
                    String despriction = user.getString("description");




                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully fetched members ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I get the response from server as

```
Register Response: {"error":false,"id":1,"member":{"name":"sidharth","profession":"singer","brief_description":"wrewt4wt4tr6e463464363","description":"ty45rt646t46436436436","filename":"upload\/Exero-Logo-top.png"}}{"error":false,"id":2,"member":{"name":"aaaaa","profession":"dwedw","brief_description":"rde3wr3w4","description":"r545w2","filename":"upload\/Exero-Logo-top.png"}}{"error":false,"id":3,"member":{"name":"fdggg","profession":"t4r54e","brief_description":"4ew5t4ew5t","description":"fdgdfg","filename":"upload\/Exero-Logo-top.png"}}
```

When I convert that response to JSONObject I only get one entry like this

```
JSON Object: {"error":false,"id":1,"member":{"name":"sidharth","profession":"singer","brief_description":"wrewt4wt4tr6e463464363","description":"ty45rt646t46436436436","filename":"upload\/Exero-Logo-top.png"}}
```

When I try to use JSONArray to get all object I got this error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"error":false,"id":1,"member":{"name":"sidharth","profession":"singer","brief_description":"wrewt4wt4tr6e463464363","description":"ty45rt646t46436436436","filename":"upload\/Exero-Logo-top.png"}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

what can I do to get all JSON Objects from response

Comment: server end json incorrect

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: json format is wrong

Comment: the response is not a valid JSON. You should not fix it, but tell the backend to fix it.

Comment: I need JSON array as my response string. What should I do in my php code  to make response JSON array